# What is the correct way to cancel a RegNotifyChangeKeyValue?

Tags: windows, winapi, registry

Asynchronous usage of `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue` is simple enough: pass it an event object and wait for the event to be signalled.

What is not so clear, however, is the correct way to cancel a notification request. For example, if a timeout has been set on the wait like so:

```
RegNotifyChangeKeyValue(hKey, false, REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_SET, regEvent.SafeWaitHandle, true);
regEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30))
```

If the timeout occurs without the notify firing, this notification is left presumably pending and waiting to fire. This is worse if the notify and wait is within a loop, potentially registering many notifications (one for each expired timeout).

Do I simply close both the event handle (`regEvent`) and the registry key handle (`hKey`)? Is there anything else I need to call, e.g. directory change notifications have `FindCloseChangeNotification`, is there an equivalent here?

---

I'm currently using P/Invoke with C#, but I do not believe that should make a difference - any answer should be focused on the requirements and usage of the Windows API. This would be much the same question if I had used `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue`/`CreateEvent`/`WaitForSingleObject` from VC++.

Comment: RegNotifyChangeKeyValue only fires once, and then is automatically cancelled until called again. You really don't need to do anything. See the [RegNotifyChangeKeyValue documentation at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regnotifychangekeyvalue)

Comment: @KenWhite In this case, the timeout is what I expect to happen -- so the notify has not fired yet. I'll edit to make that clearer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks! I must've skimmed over that line and not understood the significance. Could you make that an answer so I can vote/accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closing the open Registry key is enough. When the key is closed, the event is signaled. This is [documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regnotifychangekeyvalue). So, simply be sure to close the Registry key before freeing the event.